# OperationCanceledException when sending to Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am getting OperationCanceledException when I am sending a message to a topic queue (I am running my code from within an Azure function).
The version I am using is:  "WindowsAzure.ServiceBus": "4.1.1" (latest)
and I am getting this exception when I am doing load testing which means many messages are being sent in this service bus (which contains several topics).
I was told to use a retry mechanism as:

```
client.RetryPolicy = new RetryExponential(minBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1),
                                            maxBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                                            maxRetryCount: 3);
```

But I thought this is already done by default, doesn't it?

Would appropriate your help here - Why am I getting this exception and what can I do to resolve this?

Here is the exception:

```
Exception System.OperationCanceledException: The operation cannot be performed because the entity has been closed or aborted. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException: Internal Server Error: The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a premature session shutdown. TrackingId:88386cb1-a4e6-42e2-a8e1-bad3a2403329, Timestamp:6/6/2017 7:55:23 AM
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__9_3(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c__DisplayClass8_1.<GetAsyncSteps>b__4(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__9_3(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpTransactionalAsyncResult`1.<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__18_3(TIteratorAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult a)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.EndSendCommand(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.EndSendCommand(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.OnEndSend(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageSender.OnSend(TrackingContext trackingContext, IEnumerable`1 messages, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageSender.Send(TrackingContext trackingContext, IEnumerable`1 messages, TimeSpan timeout)
```

Answer (score 2):

Retry policy is enabled by the ASB client by default. You don't nee to do it yourself.

Exception you get is [`OperationCanceledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions) and according to documentation:

> Retry will not help.

Which is categorized as "User coding error". Looking at the exception stack trace, this is happening during send operation and the error is

> Internal Server Error: The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a premature session shutdown. TrackingId:88386cb1-a4e6-42e2-a8e1-bad3a2403329...

I'm quite sure this is not user code error, but something that took place on the broker side. The `TrackingId` supplied with the error should allow you to open a support case with Microsoft to at least have an idea what happened on the broker when that command failed.

**Edit**

Meanwhile what I would suggest it to implement your operation with an additional retry/backoff logic. Something that would not retry in a tight loop and would not depend on the client's `RetryPolicy`.